# Conditional updateItem on DynamoDB

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am fighting with updating an item in the DynamoDB table. In the documentation I noticed the next sentence:

> UpdateItem – Edits an existing item's attributes. You can also use
>   conditional operators to perform an update only if the item’s
>   attribute values match certain conditions.

I am writing on Objective-C and I cannot find any possibility for developer to set any conditions to the updateItem operation. I need the condition to be applied to the range-key.
Has anyone succeeded in conditional updating in DynamoDB?

PS. I cannot instantiate the correct writeBatchItem arguments structure. There is no info in the internet about working with DynamoDB on Objective-C :(

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states you can update attributes. The key (hash/range) is not an attribute thus cannot be updated.
Regarding the conditional update, read the API reference here: [DynamoDBUpdateItemRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/DynamoDBUpdateItemRequest.html) class reference and [set the expected values](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/DynamoDBUpdateItemRequest.html#//api/name/setExpectedValue%3aforKey%3a).

If you feel the documentation isn't clear enough you should also look at the [Java SDK Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/UpdateItemRequest.html#setExpected%28java.util.Map%29)